# Запись файла на память телефона

Tags: java, android, файлы, storage

Я хочу чтобы файлы сохранялись в отдельной папке приложения на одном уровне с папкой Downloads. Sd карты нет.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/" + folder_main + "/";
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

        int x;
        if(files != null)
            x = files.length;
        else
            x = 0;
try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(path + filename + x + ".txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
            for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : measurings.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                ArrayList<Integer> value = entry.getValue();
                for(int i : value) {
                    String s = key + ": " + i;
                    writer.println(s);
                }
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Папку создаю так

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(folder_main), folder_main);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
```

Но никакой папки не создаётся и файлов тоже. Ещё заметил что когда пытаюсь проверить допустим список файлов в папке Downloads

```
File directory1  = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File[] files2 = directory1.listFiles();
```

Выдаёт что массив `files2` пуст, хотя там точно полно файлов.
Видимо я совсем запутался в хранилищах андроида. В проводнике на самом телефоне хранилище называется внутренним (там где Downloads, DCIM, ..) но в контексте SDK internal это только то, чем владеет приложение. Как мне правильно сохранять файлы там где я хочу?

---

Почитал про функцию getExternalFilesDir, немного не то что я хотел, но этого достаточно)

Comment: Поправка, files2 = null

Comment: Если пишете приложение для конкретного аппарата - можете вписать путь хардкодом. Если для широкой аудитории - предоставьте выбор юзеру куда сохранять.